# Lua Match Everything After Character in String

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I am new to Lua, and hardly understand pattern matching. I am trying to figure out how to match everything in a string after a colon, and put that portion of the string into a variable. I haven't had much luck by looking around online, or maybe I am just not seeing it. So how would I do this?

For example, say I have a variable called `my_string` that is equal to `"hello:hi_there"` or something like that. How can I extract `"hi_there"` to a another variable without changing `my_string`?

It looks like I would need to use `string.match()`, but what pattern would be used to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing something like this:

```
local my_string = "hello:hi_there"
local extracted = string.match(my_string, ":(.*)")
print(extracted)
```

The parentheses do a pattern capture, the dot means any character and the star tells the match function that the pattern should be repeated 0 or more times. It starts matching at the `:` and takes everything until the end of the string.

Comment: i do print(string.match("hello:hi_there:erhuheriu:gg", ":(.*)")) and just need last substring ie gg after :  , any hints ?

Comment: @Altanai you can do something like `print(string.match("first:second:third",":([^:]+)$"))`. `[^:]` matches anything that is not `:` and `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't want the `:` to be in the selection, I would combine `string.find()` and `string.sub()` in the following implementation:

```
local string = "hello:hi_there"
beg, final = string.find(string, ":") # Returns the index
local new_string = string.sub(string, final + 1) # Takes the position after the colon
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html), if you left sub()'s third argument blank, it defaults to -1, so it takes all the remaining string.