# Lua pattern to remove everything after a word

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

If I have a string like this.

```
local string = "D:/Test/Stuff/Server/resources/[Test]/SuperTest"
```

How would I remove everything after the word "server" so it will end up look like this

```
local string = "D:/Test/Stuff/Server"
```

Comment: Basically, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396678/lua-match-everything-after-character-in-string).

Comment: `print(("D:/Test/Shit/Server/resources/[Test]/SuperTest"):match("(.*Server)"))`

Comment: And ```do local string=("D:/Test/Shit/Server/resources/[Test]/SuperTest"):match("(.*Server)"):gsub('/','\\') print(string) end``` corrects it to backslashes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use **str** instead of **string** to not shadow the real string library

```lua
local str = "D:/Test/Stuff/Server/resources/[Test]/SuperTest"
```

here a solution

```lua
str = str:match("(.*Server)")
```

or use **do**...**end** to avoid shadowing

```lua
do
    local string = ("D:/Test/Stuff/Server/resources/[Test]/SuperTest"):match("(.*Server)")
end
```